# How can I install and remove programs in one command line, and confirm only once?

Tags: installation, bash, uninstall

When I install Ubuntu, the first thing I usually do is remove some programs and install some others. To get that done, I enter the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get remove applicationA applicationB applicationC && sudo apt-get install applicationX applicationY applicationZ`.

This works nicely, but the problem is that I have to confirm twice: first I have to confirm the removal of the applications, and after some time I have to confirm the installation of the others. It would be great if I only had to confirm once, because I wouldn't have to come back to the computer in the meantime. Is there any command to get that done?

Please note that I'm not looking for workarounds in e.g. Synaptic Package Manager. I want to do this from the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: Use Synaptic, search, install tick "close window when installation finishes" and done

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want to use the command-line-interface, not Synaptic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-y` option for `apt-get`.

[From the **man** page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> ```
> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
>       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
>       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
>       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
> ```

So for you it would look something like `sudo apt-get remove -y foo1 foo2 foo3` and `sudo apt-get install -y foo foo1 foo2 foo3`.

Comment: OK, so in my case, the command would be: `sudo apt-get remove -y applicationA applicationB applicationC && sudo apt-get install -y applicationX applicationY applicationZ`?

Comment: Would it be `apt-get remove -y` **or** `apt-get -y remove`?

Comment: It does not matter I think.

Comment: does not matter vasa1

Answer (score 17):

As an ***alternative*** to the answers already posted, you can also select to install and remove packages in one command with `aptitude`.  With ***aptitude install*** commands add `-` after the package name to have it removed, and with ***aptitude remove*** commands add `+` after the package name to have it installed.

If you enter

`sudo aptitude install pkg1 pkg2-`

the first packages will be installed while the second one will be removed.

***However***, on the other hand, if you use

`sudo aptitude remove pkg1+ pkg2`

the second package will be removed and the first installed.

Source: for a more detailed explanation of `apt` and `aptitude`, see [the Debian Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/download/stable/debian-handbook.pdf).

Comment: Wow, that worked **so** much better than messing around with `apt-get`. I was trying to downgrade my gcc packages from 4.9 to 4.7, but that appears to be impossible with `apt-get` because *removing* gcc would remove `apt` itself (!) and downgrading is either impossible or very difficult with `apt-get`. But when I copied the exact command I'd been using with `apt-get` and replaced `apt-get` with `aptitude`, it recognized what I was trying to do, explained the problem (!), and suggested a fix (!!).

Comment: Dunno of 2012, but these days `apt-get` also has this ability, see the [answer by Benedikt Köppel](https://askubuntu.com/a/715811/113421).

Answer (score 16):

From the `apt-get` man page:

> install
>   [...] If a hyphen is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be removed if it is installed. Similarly a plus sign can be used to designate a package to install. These latter features may be used to override decisions made by apt-get's conflict resolution system.

You can append a hyphen to the package name, then apt-get will remove that package. So in order to remove package `a` and install `b`:

```
sudo apt-get install a- b
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe perform both commands using only one call to `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'apt-get remove a b c && apt-get install d e f'
```

Comment: @ScottSeverance Oh, pardon my *ignorance*, was too fast judging. Thx for the heads up ;)